# Need help in web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

New to Web Scraping and not sure what else need to be done. I am trying to scrape a web page using python and beautifulsoup to gather all the reviews/user id and the ratings.

link - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.avod.thirdpartyclient&hl=en_US

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.avod.thirdpartyclient&hl=en_US').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
review = soup.find('div')
print(review.prettify())
```

After this line when i try to find the reviews. it returns None. I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

Comment: "Why doesn't my code work?" type questions are off-topic

Comment: Check `source` to see if it has what you expect. You can write it directly to an HTML file and then open it in your browser. For more debugging tips, see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @dfundako They are only off-topic if they do not contain "the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it ". As this question has an MVE, the desired behavior, and the exact problem they are facing, it is not off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before scraping it is good to look on [page source](https://www.howtogeek.com/416108/how-to-view-the-html-source-in-google-chrome/). If you dont see your tags in page source you have few options. You can try to look into script tags and in lots of cases you can find your data there (but you need to do few string operations to get them) or in different case you can inspect, where webpage makes requests during loading - this could help you find naked api points, which you could use to get data. 
Or if you dont find data in script tags or any naked api points than you can use selenium to execute javascript ( another option is to use browser with your custom plugin - which helps you to control browser)

In your case your reviews data are in script tag (javascript in browser will generate div tags with reviews, but to execute javascript you need selenium or browser with your custom written plugin). 
There are more scripts tags but you can identify script tag with reviews data thanks to this string: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a- (part of link to user which gave review).

In your case something like this could work:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.avod.thirdpartyclient&hl=en_US')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
scripts = soup.findAll('script')
review_script = None
for script in scripts:
    if "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-" in script.text:
        review_script = script.text
        break
#in script tag there is function which returns data which you want
#there are few parts which needs to be removed to get nested list with data
data = json.loads(review_script.split('return')[-1].split('}});')[0]) #}});
#here are review data in nested list needs some playing with it
reviews = data[0]
#modify as needed
for review in reviews:
    user = review[1][0]
    review = review[4]
    print(user, review)
```

Comment: Thanks, the code works. What i am trying to figure out is how to read the data from the output we get. Is there a document or blog that i can refer to so that i can get well-verse with it. e.g how do i read the star rating that was provided.

Comment: yes, function is returning array of arrays (array in javascript is similar to python list), javascript is passing data around mostly as json, it is good to understand json https://www.json.org/ .Each case is different (because different developers are using different logic to pass data around) and as you see in your it is multilevel nested list. You need just look what data are on various position of this nested list. Not sure if helped.

Comment: yea, kind off, i was still not able to figure out how you came up with these,           
      user = review[1][0]
    review = review[4], any additional inputs will help!